# VSCODE : get error after install php_codesniffer

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, phpcodesniffer

I have Laravel project always get error message from vscode about phpcs ,I searched for solving ,I found to excecute this line command :

```
 composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer
```

after I did I get errors in my controllers and api pages :
[image]

I removed php_codesniffer again but not solved

Comment: Is your project is working? Please see this instruction https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs

Comment: @A.ANoman yes works fine

Comment: CodeSniffer wants you to comment your methods with a [docblock](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/getting-started/what-is-a-docblock.html) & to camelCase your methods names instead of snake_casing them (i.e., `postCategories` instead of `post_categories`).